# When I delete an email it is still in my All Mail folder

Tags: gmail

When I delete email from my inbox, it is still there in "All Mail" folder.
why are they still there when deleted from inbox?

Is there a way to prevent email from going to "All Mail" folder?

Answer (score 3):

First of all some important items:

- Gmail doesn't have folders, it has labels.
- Each message can have multiple labels.
- Inbox is a label. when you archive a message the inbox label is stripped from the message. If there are more labels on the message it doesn't touch those labels
- All messages except those with trash or spam labels are found with the label "all mail"

When a new message is received, it essentially is given the "all mail" label and the "inbox" label. If there are rules/filters in place additional labels can be attached, or the inbox label can be stripped.

> When I delete email from my inbox, it is still there in "All Mail"
> folder. why are they still there when deleted from inbox?

- If you used the archive button, the email will either have no labels except "all mail"; or it will have any labels previously attached to the email.
- If you used the delete button. The email is only found with the label trash.

Comment: This is not correct, I’ve deleted All mail and a few days later it’s full again with emails that are over 3 months old and I know for a fact I have deleted them all numerous times. Also all mail under any label appears and I move it back to its label but with all the deleted messages my labeled ones show up also.